# Comprobar si un valor está en una lista encadenada

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Quiero implementar un método que admita como parámetro un valor. El método devolverá True si el valor pasado como parámetro se encuentra en la lista y False si no. He intentado lo siguiente pero obtengo un **error de tipo** **AtributeError: int object is not iterable**

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente:

```
def check(self, valor):
    for nodo in self:
        if nodo.value == valor:
           return True
        else:
           return False
```

Adjunto también la clase que cree para que puedan ver los atributos existentes:

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
            self.value = value
            self.next_node = next_node

    def __init__(self):
        self.__first = None
        self.__len = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.__len

    def __iter__(self):
        self.__current = self.__first
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.__current != None:
            result = self.__current.value
            self.__current = self.__current.next_node
            return result
        else:
           raise StopIteration
```

Comment: Hola. Procura incluir el mensaje completo de error, por favor.

Comment: Sería práctico simplificar el código mostrado para indicar solamente lo esencial, así como proveer un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas con tu código:

Primero, implementas el protocolo iterador mediante:

```
def __iter__(self):
    self.__current = self.__first
    return self

def __next__(self):
    if self.__current != None:
        result = self.__current.value
        self.__current = self.__current.next_node
        return result
    else:
        raise StopIteration
```

Es decir, el iterador generado por tu clase itera sobre los valores de los nodos  de la lista no sobre sus nodos directamente. Por lo tanto la comapración no debe ser:

```
for nodo in self:
    if nodo.value == valor:
```

sino:

```
for value in self:
    if value == valor:
```

Por otro lado, el `else` no puede estar ahí. Si el primer valor resulta no se el buscado se retorna automáticamente False, cuando solo debe retronarse `False` si tras recorrer toda la lista el valor no se encuentra.

Por lo tanto debería ser:

```
def check(self, valor):
    for value in self:
        if value == valor:
           return True
    return False
```

Después de todo el rollo, realmente es todo mucho más simple, usa el operador de pertenencia sin más:

```
def check(self, valor):
    return valor in self
```

Lo mismo que causaba tu fallo, la forma en la que implementas el protocolo iterador, permite usar `in` directamente.

PD.  `if self.__current != None:` no es técnicamente correcto, se debe usar el operador de identidad con `None`, `if self.__current is not None:`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias